# How to extract text between two tags in Perl?

Tags: html, perl, html-parsing

You can see the html page here, it was pasted there.

This is the HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<!-- saved from url=(0066)http://www.eng.bahcesehir.edu.tr/openconf/chair/assign_reviews.php -->
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>AHS-2006 - OpenConf Conference Management System</TITLE>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<STYLE type=text/css>@import url( ../openconf.css );
</STYLE>

<META content="MSHTML 6.00.2900.2802" name=GENERATOR></HEAD>
<BODY bgColor=#ffffff leftMargin=0 topMargin=0 rightMargin=0 marginwidth="0" 
marginheight="0">
<DIV class=conf><A class=confName 
href="http://ehw.jpl.nasa.gov/events/ahs2006/">1st Conference on Adaptive 
Hardware and Systems (AHS-2006)</A></DIV>
<DIV class=menuoc>OpenConf Conference Management System</DIV>
<DIV class=menu>
<DIV class=menuitem><A 
href="http://www.eng.bahcesehir.edu.tr/openconf/chair/">Chair Home</A></DIV>
<DIV class=menuitem><A 
href="http://www.eng.bahcesehir.edu.tr/openconf/chair/signout.php">Sign 
Out</A></DIV>
<DIV class=menufiller>Logged in as: ahs2006&nbsp;</DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=mainbody><BR>
<P class=header>Assign Reviews</P>
<FORM action=/openconf/chair/assign_reviews.php method=post>
<DL>
  <DT>
  <P><B>Select Paper(s):</B></P>
  <DD>
  <P>[ Paper ID - Title (# Reviewers) ]</P>
  <DD><SELECT multiple size=10 name=papers[]> <OPTION value=2>&nbsp;&nbsp;2 - 
    Switchable Glass: A possible medium for Evolvable Hardware (4)</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=3>&nbsp;&nbsp;3 - An Efficient Multi-Objective Evolutionary 
    Algorithm for Combinational Circuit Design (3)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=4>&nbsp;&nbsp;4 - A Background Mismatch Calibration for Capacitive 
    Digital-to-Analog Converters (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=5>&nbsp;&nbsp;5 - 
    Designing Electronic Circuits by Means of Gene Expression Programming 
    (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=6>&nbsp;&nbsp;6 - Coherence Based Fault Detection 
    And Error Correction (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=7>&nbsp;&nbsp;7 - Wormhole 
    Routing with Virtual Channels using Dynamic Rate Control for Network-on... 
    (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=8>&nbsp;&nbsp;8 - Noise Analysis of Phase Locked 
    Loops (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=9>&nbsp;&nbsp;9 - Design and Analysis of a 
    Second Order Phase Locked Loops (PLLs) (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=10>10 - 
    SW-HW Co-design and fault tolerant implementation for the LRID Wireless 
    communication... (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=11>11 - Adaptive PID Controller 
    Using Parameter Optimization Algorithm (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=12>12 - A 
    Novel Self-organizing Hybrid Network Protocol (2)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=13>13 - An Adaptive FPGA-Based Mechatronic Control System Supporting 
    Partial Reconfiguration... (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=14>14 - Generalized 
    Disjunction Decomposition for the Evolution of Programmable Logic Array... 
    (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=15>15 - Woofer-Tweeter Adaptive Optics System 
    (1)</OPTION> <OPTION value=16>16 - A Re-Programmable Platform for Dynamic 
    Burn-in Test of Xilinx VirtexII 3000 FPGA... (3)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=17>17 - Using hardware-based particle swarm method for dynamic 
    optimization of adaptive ... (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=18>18 - 
    Hardware/software coevolution of genome programs and cellular processors 
    (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=19>19 - Systolic Array Based Adaptive Beamformer 
    Modelling in SystemC Environment (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=20>20 - A 
    Reconfigurable Hardware Design Using FPGA (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=21>21 - 
    An FPGA Implemented Processor Architecture with Adaptive Resolution 
    (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=22>22 - Evolving Hardware with 
    Self-reconfigurable connectivity in Xilinx FPGAs (2)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=23>23 - Particle Swarm Optimization with Discrete Recombination: An 
    Online Optimizer for... (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=24>24 - Towards the 
    Integration of Drive Control Loop Electronics of the JPL/Boeing Gyroscope... 
    (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=25>25 - An Incremental Evolutionary Strategy for 
    the Design of FIR Filters Targeting Real... (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=26>26 
    - Adaptive Micro-Antenna on Silicon Substrate (3)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=27>27 - Towards Fluent Sensor Networks: A Scalable and Robust 
    Self-Deployment Approach (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=28>28 - Comparison of 
    Fuzzy-C Means, Hard C-Means and Differential Evolution Algorithm in... 
    (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=29>29 - Evolutionary Design of Digital Circuits: 
    Where Are Current Limits? (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=30>30 - GEZGİN &amp; 
    GEZGİN-2: Adaptive Real-Time Image Processing Subsystems for Earth 
    Observing... (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=31>31 - A Multi-objective Genetic 
    Algorithm for On-chip Real-time Adaptation of a Multi-... (2)</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=32>32 - An Efficient Technique for Preventing Single Event 
    Disruptions in Synchronous and... (1)</OPTION> <OPTION value=33>33 - 
    Architecture of a Dynamically Reconfigurable NoC for Adaptive Reconfigurable 
    MPSoC (0)</OPTION> <OPTION value=34>34 - Embedded Reconfigurable Array 
    Fabrics for Efficient Implementation of Image Compression... (1)</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=35>35 - Routing in Wireless Sensor Networks Using Ant Colony 
    Optimization (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=36>36 - Simulation of 
    Multifunctional Combinational Modules Controlled by Vdd (3)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=37>37 - Reconfigurable Parallel Computing Architecture for On-Board 
    Data Processing (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=38>38 - On comparison of Variable 
    Length Representations by Means of Unconstrained Evolution... (3)</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=39>39 - VLSI Implementation of LMS Equaliser with Adaptive 
    Length Selection for Wireless... (0)</OPTION> <OPTION value=41>41 - A 
    Scalable Reconfigurable Analog to Digital Converter Architecture Targeting 
    Low... (0)</OPTION> <OPTION value=42>42 - Linear Prediction with 
    Differential Evolution Algorithm (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=43>43 - Genetic 
    Algorithm based Engine for Domain-Specific Reconfigurable Arrays 
    (0)</OPTION> <OPTION value=44>44 - Non-Uniform Search Domain based Genetic 
    Algorithm for the Synthesis and Continuous... (2)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=45>45 - Design Concepts for a Dynamically Reconfigurable Wireless 
    Sensor Node (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=46>46 - On-Board Partial Run-Time 
    Reconfiguration for Pico-Satellite Constellations (2)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=47>47 - A Framework of Evolvable and Reconfigurable Sensor Networks 
    for Aerospace –based... (0)</OPTION> <OPTION value=48>48 - Analytical 
    Modelling of Power Attenuation under Parameter Fluctuations with 
    Applications... (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=49>49 - A New State Space 
    Representation Method for Adaptive Log Domain Systems (2)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=50>50 - Swarm Based Incremental Learning for Combinational Circuit 
    Evolution (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=51>51 - Gene Regulation Mechanisms 
    introduced in the E valuation Criteria for a Hardware... (2)</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=52>52 - Automatic Hybrid Genetic Algorithm Based Printed 
    Circuit Board Inspection (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=53>53 - Population based 
    FPGA solution to Mastermind game (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=54>54 - A Large 
    Scale Adaptable Multiplier for Cryptographic Applications (2)</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=55>55 - A Self-Tuning Analog Proportional-Integral-Derivative 
    (PID) Controller (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=56>56 - Self-Configurable Neural 
    Network Processor for Adaptable FIR Filters (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=57>57 
    - On-Chip Evolution Using a Soft Processor Core Applied to Image Recognition 
    (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=58>58 - A Novel Adaptive Viterbi Algorithm and 
    Its Implementation (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=59>59 - An Efficient Hardware 
    Architecture for H.264 Adaptive Deblocking Filter (2)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=60>60 - A Low-Complexity Self-Calibrating Adaptive Quadrature Receiver 
    (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=61>61 - A Honeycomb Development Architecture for 
    Robust Fault-Tolerant Design (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=62>62 - Sate-Space 
    based Analytical Modelling for Real-Time Fault Recovery and Self-Repair... 
    (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=63>63 - Strategies to On- Line Failure Recovery 
    in Self- Adaptive Systems based on Dynamic... (2)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=64>64 - A Platform for Digital Intrinsic Hardware Evolution 
    (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=65>65 - Face Recognition Using a Gabor Filter 
    Bank Approach (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=66>66 - Protecting Fingerprint Data 
    using Watermarking (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=67>67 - Debug Support for 
    System-on-Chips, Considerations for Reconfigurable and Hybrid ... 
    (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=68>68 - Novel Techniques for Ensuring Secure 
    Communications for Distributed Low Power Devices (2)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=69>69 - A Modular Framework for the Evolution of Circuits on 
    Configurable Transistor Array... (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=70>70 - Power 
    Driven Reconfigurable Complex Continuous Wavelet Transform Processor 
    (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=71>71 - A Tuning Technique for Switched-Capacitor 
    Circuits (0)</OPTION> <OPTION value=72>72 - An Automatic Technique to 
    Synthesize System-on-a-Chip to Adapt to Changing Environments (2)</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=73>73 - Picosatellite Constellations for Remote Sensing in LEO 
    (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=74>74 - Evolvable Hardware Applied to 
    Nanotechnology (1)</OPTION> <OPTION value=75>75 - Gate-level Morphogenetic 
    Evolvable Hardware for Scalability and Adaptation on FPGAs (2)</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=76>76 - Synthesis of MOS Analog Circuits by Evolutionary 
    Methods (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=77>77 - An Adaptive HDL Design 
    Methodology for Hard IP and Soft IP Co-Protection (2)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=78>78 - FSM and HSM watermarking: A Tutorial (3)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=79>79 - Physics-based Model applied to Evolvable Hardware (2)</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=80>80 - A Generic On-Chip Debugger for Wireless Sensor 
    Networks (goCDWSN) (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=81>81 - The Gannet 
    Service-based SoC: A Service-level Reconfigurable Architecture (2)</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=82>82 - A FPGA simulation using asexual genetic algorithms for 
    integrated self-repair (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=83>83 - USING THE 
    “CELOXICA” FPGA BOARD AND THE MACHINE LEARNING ALGORITHM “LEM3‮.. 
    (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=84>84 - A Comparing Design of Satellite Attitude 
    Control System Based on Reaction Wheel (0)</OPTION></SELECT> 
  <P></P>
  <DT>
  <P><B>Select Reviewer(s):</B></P>
  <DD>
  <P><SPAN class=note>Tip: Click on ID, Name, or Reviews on the line below to 
  re-sort this list (page will reload)</SPAN></P>
  <DD>
  <P>[ Reviewer ID - <A 
  href="http://www.eng.bahcesehir.edu.tr/openconf/chair/assign_reviews.php?s=name">Name</A> 
  (# <A 
  href="http://www.eng.bahcesehir.edu.tr/openconf/chair/assign_reviews.php?s=reviews">Reviews</A>) 
  ]</P>
  <DD><SELECT multiple size=10 name=reviewers[]> <OPTION value=4>&nbsp;&nbsp;4 
    - [PC] Nizamettin Aydin (0)</OPTION> <OPTION value=5>&nbsp;&nbsp;5 - [PC] 
    Yalcin Cekic (0)</OPTION> <OPTION value=6>&nbsp;&nbsp;6 - [PC] Didier 
    Keymeulen (1)</OPTION> <OPTION value=7>&nbsp;&nbsp;7 - [PC] Emin Anarim 
    (0)</OPTION> <OPTION value=8>&nbsp;&nbsp;8 - [PC] Murat Askar (0)</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=9>&nbsp;&nbsp;9 - [PC] Peter Athanas (3)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=10>10 - [PC] Juergen Becker (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=11>11 - [PC] 
    Neil Bergmann (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=12>12 - [PC] John Choma 
    (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=13>13 - [PC] Carlos A. Coello Coello (3)</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=14>14 - [PC] Sorin Cristoloveanu (1)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=15>15 - [PC] Antonio Di Nola (1)</OPTION> <OPTION value=16>16 - [PC] 
    Wai-Chi Fang (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=17>17 - [PC] F. Joel Ferguson 
    (0)</OPTION> <OPTION value=18>18 - [PC] Dario Floreano (1)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=19>19 - [PC] Manfred Glesner (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=20>20 - [PC] 
    Maya Gokhale (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=21>21 - [PC] Pauline Haddow 
    (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=22>22 - [PC] Ilker Hamzaoglu (1)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=23>23 - [PC] Tetsuya Higuchi (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=24>24 - [PC] 
    Daniel Howard (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=25>25 - [PC] Lishan Kang 
    (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=26>26 - [PC] Haluk Konuk (3)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=27>27 - [PC] John Koza (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=28>28 - [PC] Jason 
    Lahn (1)</OPTION> <OPTION value=29>29 - [PC] Bernard Manderick (3)</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=30>30 - [PC] Trent McConaghy (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=31>31 
    - [PC] Bob McKay (1)</OPTION> <OPTION value=32>32 - [PC] Brian Meadows 
    (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=33>33 - [PC] Karlheinz Meier (2)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=34>34 - [PC] Mohammad Mojarradi (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=35>35 - 
    [PC] J. M. Moreno (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=36>36 - [PC] Masahiro Murakawa 
    (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=37>37 - [PC] Alex Orailoglu (0)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=38>38 - [PC] Christos Papachristou (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=39>39 - 
    [PC] Marek A. Perkowski (1)</OPTION> <OPTION value=40>40 - [PC] Viktor 
    Prasanna (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=41>41 - [PC] Justinian Rosca 
    (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=42>42 - [PC] Eduardo Sanchez (3)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=43>43 - [PC] Radu Secareanu (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=44>44 - [PC] 
    Sakir Sezer (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=45>45 - [PC] Hajime Shibata 
    (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=46>46 - [PC] Horia-Nicolai Teodorescu 
    (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=47>47 - [PC] Jim Torresen (3)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=48>48 - [PC] Andy Tyrrell (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=49>49 - [PC] 
    Sezer Goren Ugurdag (0)</OPTION> <OPTION value=50>50 - [PC] Ranga Vemuri 
    (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=51>51 - [PC] Tanya Vladimirova (3)</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=52>52 - [PC] Svetlana Yanushkevich (3)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=53>53 - [PC] Xin Yao (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=54>54 - [PC] Nukhet 
    Yetis (0)</OPTION> <OPTION value=55>55 - [PC] Sanyou Zeng (3)</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=56>56 - [PC] Nazeeh Aranki (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=57>57 - 
    [PC] Hugo deGaris (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=58>58 - [PC] Erik Dirkx 
    (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=59>59 - [PC] Ahmet Erdogan (2)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=60>60 - [PC] Sharon Graves (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=61>61 - [PC] 
    David Gwaltney (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=62>62 - [PC] Alister Hamilton 
    (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=63>63 - [PC] Alan Hunsberger (3)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=64>64 - [PC] Srinivas Katkoori (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=65>65 - [PC] 
    Semion Kizhner (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=66>66 - [PC] Gregory Larchev 
    (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=67>67 - [PC] Derek Linden (1)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=68>68 - [PC] Klaus McDonald-Maier (1)</OPTION> <OPTION value=69>69 - 
    [PC] Julian Miller (1)</OPTION> <OPTION value=70>70 - [PC] Lukas Sekanina 
    (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=71>71 - [PC] Raphael Some (3)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=72>72 - [PC] Adrian Stoica (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=73>73 - [PC] 
    Gianluca Tempesti (1)</OPTION> <OPTION value=74>74 - [PC] Anil Thakoor 
    (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=75>75 - [PC] Gunnar Tufte (3)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=76>76 - [PC] Tina Yu (2)</OPTION> <OPTION value=77>77 - [PC] Rolf 
    Drechsler (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=78>78 - [PC] Rajesh Galivanche 
    (3)</OPTION> <OPTION value=79>79 - [PC] Paul Hasler (2)</OPTION> <OPTION 
    value=80>80 - [PC] Kalmanje S Krishnakumar (0)</OPTION> <OPTION value=81>81 
    - [PC] Osman Nuri Ucan (0)</OPTION> <OPTION value=82>82 - [PC] H Fatih 
    Ugurdag (0)</OPTION></SELECT> 
  <P></P>
  <DT><INPUT type=submit value="Assign Reviews" name=submit> </DT></DL></FORM>
<P></P></DIV><!-- mainbody -->
<P>&nbsp;</P>
<DIV class=footerBorder></DIV><!-- DO NOT REMOVE THIS COPYRIGHT NOTICE -->
<P>
<DIV class=powered>Powered by <A href="http://www.openconf.org/" 
target=_blank>OpenConf</A><!--1.22--><BR>Copyright ©2002-2005 <A 
href="http://www.zakongroup.com/technology/" target=_blank>Zakon Group 
LLC</A></DIV><!-- DO NOT REMOVE THIS COPYRIGHT NOTICE --></BODY></HTML>
```

I need to extract the text after the line

```
Paper ID - Title (# Reviewers)
```

until

```
Select Reviewer(s):
```

I did this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use English qw(-no_match_vars);
use Carp;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
my $f = 'index.html';
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
$tree->parse_file($f);

my @options = $tree->find('OPTION');
foreach (@options){
    print $_->as_text,"\n";    
}
$tree->delete; #clear memory
sleep(131);
```

but it can not extract what i want. I could not manage to use with end tags.

Comment: What happened when you tried that code?  What answer did you get that was wrong?  What did you want it to do?  Tell us more about your expectations and actual results.

Comment: That code gave me all text, not that part. When i try with end tags, it did not work. I want the text between two tags.

Comment: @CursedChico It's obvious you are from Yeditepe University.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done by Regex

```
my ($required_text) = $all_string =~ /Paper ID - Title \\(\\# Reviewers\\)(.*?)Select Reviewer\\(s\\):/sg;

Print $required_text."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
# load the page into a string, let's call it $all
my $p0 = index($all, "Paper ID Title");
if ($p0 > -1) { my $p1 = index($all, "\>", $p0);
  if ($p1 > -1) { my $p2 = index($all, "Select Reviewer(s):", $p1);
     if ($p2 > -1) { my $target = substr($all, $p1, ($p2 - $p1)); } } }
```

Comment: Where is the input file?